# Order of generation in the VEGAS algorithm

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo, algorithms

The VEGAS algorithm is a way of efficiently generating Monte Carlo events.  In the first iteration, it generates an n-dimensional (n can be configured) set of uniformly distributed random numbers between 0 and 1, and calls a user specified function that returns its probability.  As it does this, it also saves information about where accepted events are highly concentrated and uses this information to optimize its distribution of random numbers in the next iteration to make it more efficient.  VEGAS integrates over the distribution and gives the total integral and its error at the end of each iteration.

The function called can do whatever you want.  In our case, we also use the probability calculated, multiplied a factor given to the function by vegas to compensate for the optimized distribution, to do accept/reject sampling and generate events.  We have checked that this method works and gives the expected distributions.

There is also a flag, called `stopvegas`, that can be set by the calling function to stop an iteration in the middle.  We use this for the purpose of generating a predetermined number of events, since there's no guarantee that this number will be reached at the end of an iteration.

The issue with this is that the numbers appear to be generated in a deterministic order; in each event, the first random number is bigger than in the previous event.  This means that if `stopvegas` is set, the results are nonsense.  There is a switch in the VEGAS code called `mds` that appears to fix this issue if set to 0, but we are not sure if it actually generates the numbers in a random order, or if it does something else (like ordering in the last random number instead of the first, which wouldn't help).

Does anyone familiar with the algorithm and its code know what `mds` actually does?

The code we use is [here](https://github.com/JHUGen/JHUGen/blob/master/JHUGenerator/vegas/vegas.f), for reference.  (Warning: if you are not familiar with the algorithm and are not used to reading very old code with lots of gotos and nondescriptive variable names, you will not have much success.)

Comment: I don't know if this is the right site for this question.  If not I apologize, feel free to migrate it somewhere more appropriate.

Comment: Can you add more detail / context? It's hard to tell what this is about, and people aren't going to want to navigate elsewhere and read a lot to understand and answer your question for you.

Comment: @gung I don't think this question is answerable by people not already familiar with the algorithm and its code, I was hoping there are some of those people here.  It was written a long time ago, when gotos were common and variable names were not obvious; it was normal at the time but for people used to reading more recent code it's a mess.  That's why I can't answer the question myself.  If that makes this a bad question let me know and I'll delete it.